# New .railsrc giving me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, .railsrc

I am running Rails 3.2.6 and in my `.railsrc` file I have `-d postgresql -T`. Whenever I run `rails c` on my app, it gives me an error

```
in `load': /Users/user/.railsrc:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: i test on my project and it's working fine

Comment: That's strange. This is also my first time using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to write every option from new line as follow:

```
--skip-test-unit
-d postgresql
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**`-T`** is alias of **`--skip-test-unit`**.

You should add each flags one by one in .railsrc file. Otherwise just add the following command in the same.

**`ruby -d postgresql -T`** or

**`ruby -d postgresql --skip-test-unit`**